# Metrics on derived smooth manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, derived-algebraic-geometry

Derived geometry explains how to remove the transversality condition and make sense out of a nontransversal intersection.
For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are embedded submanifolds of a manifold (or spaceform) $Z$, then the intersection of $X$ and $Y$ is a derived manifold of dimension $\dim X+\dim Y-\dim Z$, which can be negative.

For a derived manifold of dimension $-2$, how I can write its metric?
Can someone give me an example of such a metric?

Comment: You could try to define Riemannian metrics for derived manifolds in terms of the cotangent complex $L_X$, but non-degeneracy will only be possible when the cotangent complex is concentrated in degree $0$, thus excluding manifolds of negative dimension. However, under some circumstances, some form of $n$-shifted Riemannian metric may be possible, i.e. $L_X^* \simeq L_X[n]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I don't know how to get a metric for manifold with negative dimension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is nothing in the literature that
treats Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian metrics on derived smooth manifolds.
However, there is an extensive treatment of symplectic structures
on derived stacks by Pantev, Toën, Vaquié, and Vezzosi:
[Shifted symplectic structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3209).

Due to the Koszul sign rule, a pseudosymplectic structure (i.e., a symplectic structure without the integrability condition) is nothing else
than a pseudo-Riemannian metric on the cotangent complex shifted in degree by 1.

Comment: Dear prof. Pavlov, thank you very much for your help.
So I can consider a -2-dimensional derived-manifold as a derived manifold endowed with -2-shifted symplectic structure, is correct?
Then like a metric for a -2-dimensional derived-manifold, can I consider a 2-symplectic structure metric on a derived stack?

Comment: A symplectic form has more restrictions than a shifted pseudo-Riemannian metric, because of the closure conditions or closing structures. For shifted symplectic structures in the smooth setting, see arXiv:1804.07622.In answer to the OP's comment, n-shifted and n-dimensional are very different.

Comment: how can I get a metric for negative dimensional manifold?

Comment: @OP u would do well to be a bit clearer re what u want here. As Pridham mentions there's a shift involved, a good basic example would be the odd line over the reals. The simplest care should be real derived vec spaces (chain complexes that is) with non deg *shifted* symm forms, nb that unlike in the case of non derived vec spaces such a form needn't exist (it implies a certain symmetry on the cohom groups)

Comment: Dear EBz thank you for your reply, I would like to find an example of a derive manifold with negative dimension and to be able to write down its metric (for example to understand how to define the distance between points on it).

Comment: @exxxit8: If points are understood in the usual sense, than most of the structure of a derived manifold is irrelevant: points in M are morphisms pt→M, which translates to a morphism of C^∞-dgas C^∞(M)→C^∞(pt)=**R**, which is the same thing as π_0(C^∞(M))→**R**, i.e., a point in the underlying ordinary smooth space of M.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: Thank you so much for the precious answer. So if I mean the points in the usual sense, also their distance can be described with a usual pseudo-riemannian metric?

Comment: @exxxit8: Yes.  The derived part can be thought of as an infinitesimal thickening of some kind, so it does not affect distances between ordinary points.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavolv: Ok, thank you very much again.

Comment: ..in the case of derived manifolds with a negative dimension, however, it is difficult to define what a point is ... what size does a point have? because if we consider it in the classical way it has a zero dimension and therefore it can not be contained in a derived-manifold with a negative dimension because it would have a larger dimension.

Comment: @exxxit8: A point in a derived manifold M is simply a morphism of derived manifolds pt→M.